# JPA executes select statements two times before insert operation

Tags: jpa

I am trying to persist multiple entities, while doing so firing some select commands for insertion.I have say 3 select commands before insertion, then all these select commands are getting fire one more time before insert operation, can any body answer this ?

Comment: include your code and the SQL log

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem, Here is my solution, will help somebody else

To prevent the second time SELECT before INSERT, use `Session.load()` or `EntityManager.getReference()`

```
User u = new User();
u.setUserStatusType( session.load(UserStatusType.class, new Long(id));
session.persis(u);
```

The `session.load()` method doesn't initially load anything, it just creates a proxy for the object and avoids a hit to the database.

Here the id parameter passed in `session.load()` is from select sql which I have fired earlier, and my concern was I was getting the same sql statement one more time which hibernate is doing, now I stopped hibernate framework from firing the same select sql again using load method and now only one select statement is getting fired and not the extra one which hibernate was doing automatically.